# NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport with search form OR condition implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() to query the db.

Is there a better way I can map the form fields on the query, if value entered in the form fields should be included in where condition, else don't include the condition?

Currently using like:

**getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(QUERY_TEST, namedParams, valueObjectMapper);**

Comment: have you find it by now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible for you, but instead of using a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` you could use the `HibernateTemplate` instead. Then you could use [Example Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples).

So basically you would create an instance of the object you are searching for based on the values entered in the form field. (By default only those fields that have a value set are considered by Hibernate for the where clause)

Then your code would roughly look like this:

```
getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<YourClass>() {

        @Override
        public List<YourClass> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

            Criteria yourClassCriteria = session.createCriteria(YourClass.class);
            Example exampleCriteria = Example.create(yourClassInstance); 
            yourClassCriteria.add(exampleCriteria);

            return yourClassCriteria.list();
        }
    });
```

Obviously you would need to replace `YourClass` with the type that you are actually searching for and `yourClassInstance` is the instance created based on the values from the form.

Hope that helps.